# DIsplay LiveData in a ListView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, dao

I have an `Activity` where I have a `LiveData` and I wanna display it in a `ListView`.

My code snippet:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_records)
    this.recordListView.emptyView = recordListEmptyView
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(RecordsViewModel::class.java)
    recordDAO = AppDatabase.getDb(this).recordDao()
    recordDAO.findAllSync().observe(this) {
        //display livedata in listview after getting added
        //adapter = ArrayAdapter(this,list_items,syncedRecords)
        //listview.adapter = adapter
    }
}
```

After I added a record I wanna display the records in the place where I have the comment.
I could make it work with a normal `findAll()` and set my adapter to the return of `findAll()` but I could not make it work with `LiveData`.

My DAO class:

```
@Dao
interface RecordDAO{

    @Update(onConflict = REPLACE)
    fun update(record:Record) : Int

    @Insert(onConflict = IGNORE)
    fun persist(record: Record): Long

    @Delete
    fun delete(record: Record): Int

    @Delete
    fun deleteAll(records: List<Record>)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM record")
    fun findAll(): List<Record>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM record")
    fun findAllSync(): LiveData<List<Record>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM record WHERE id = :id")
    fun findById(id: Int): Record?

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it should work. Since you did not inclue the viewmodel code, it is difficult to know the exact error. Here you observe the result of a function (`recordDAO.findAllSync().observe`), so I guess that the livedata is a variable only in the scope of `findAllSync`.

This is not how it works. Live data should be a member variable of the viewModel

```
class RecordsViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val records = MutableLiveData<RecordDAO>()

    // this function gives the records to the live data. No need for a return value
    fun findAllSync() {
        // Retrieve the records somehow, here this should be edited by you
        records.value = someService.getRecords()
    }
}
```

Then in the activity/fragment, you observe the live data and request a record update (You can also request the update directly from the `init` of the viewmodel depending on how/when you want to get the data)

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_records)
    this.recordListView.emptyView = recordListEmptyView
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(RecordsViewModel::class.java)
    
    // THIS CHANGED
    viewModel.findAllSync()
    viewModel.records.observe(this) { records ->
        val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this,list_items, records)
        listview.adapter = adapter
    }
}
```

**Note:** I used a `MutableLiveData`. The cleaner way is to have a private `MutableLiveData` and a public `LiveData`

```
private val _records = MutableLiveData<RecordDAO>()
val records: LiveData<RecordDAO> = _records
```

The vm uses `_records.value` to set the data but since the Activity can only read the non mutable one, it cannot edit the value, only the viewmodel can. You don't need to do it this way it but it's always nice to know

Comment: I did not have any error but the records were not displayed was the problem

Comment: I do not quite understand this, is the findAllSync method in the viewmodel used anywhere?

Comment: @YasinEraslan sorry, just a line missing in my answer. Check the lines where I added the comment // THIS CHANGED

Comment: Where does the recordDao.records come from?

Comment: And what u mean by service i actually only have a sql database , with findAll()( I can get all records from my database

Comment: Sorry again, this time the answer should be correct. It was `viewModel.records`.
A service is a common name for a class or module that provides the data, so in your case, put there any class or function call that gets the data from the database

Comment: That seems more likely to work, but i thouht the observe works like this that if there is a new record in the database that i can just get it from the observe directly and display it , so I was thinking wrong?

Comment: Sadly when I add a record it doesnt get updated

Comment: It will be called only when you updated value field of the livedata.
The view model has to update it when adding a record. That's just how the viewmodel+livedata works